# How can I run a shell script (*.sh) using R in linux?

Tags: r, bash, shell

I would like to run a shell script (e.g., `f.sh`) using R.

I tried `system("f.sh")` but it does not work, could someone please help me in this?

Comment: Make sure you a) have a 'shebang line' of `#!/bin/sh` at the top and b) executable mode (`chmod 0755 f.sh` may help) and that you c) can run the script in shell.  If all that holds then `system("f.sh")` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
bashscript <- "./script.sh"
system(bashscript)
```

Comment: Great, Many Thanks

Comment: On Windows, `cmdscript <- "./script.cmd"
system(cmdscript) `